# Solr suddenly shutsdown gracefully

Tags: solr, jetty, solrcloud

I searched a lot for this problem but I can't find many resources concerning this issue.

We are running a set-up of SolrCloud on 2 FreeBsd servers. Every night at exactly 12:00 our Solr servers are somehow being shutdown gracefully internally by solr. Strange is that both solr-servers are being restarted.

I don't have any clu what the cause is, it seems that Jetty is the possible cause with the setting "stopAtShutdown" and "gracefulShutdown" but I am not sure what the reason is for restarting solr.

Some log lines:

```
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:01.056; org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server; Graceful shutdown SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:01.057; org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server; Graceful shutdown o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/usr/local/share/examples/apache-solr/solr-webapp/webapp/},/usr/local/share/examples/apa
che-solr/webapps/solr.war
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.064; org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer; Shutting down CoreContainer instance=568196821
WARN  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.065; org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy; Stopping recovery for core=X_shard1_replica2 coreNodeName=core_node1
WARN  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.065; org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy; Stopping recovery for core=Y_shard1_replica1 coreNodeName=core_node1
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.065; org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController; publishing core=Z_shard1_replica1 state=down collection=Z
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.073; org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController; publishing core=Zoetermeer_Openbaar_shard1_replica2 state=down collection=Zoetermeer_Openbaar
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.102; org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController; publishing core=X_shard1_replica2 state=down collection=X
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.110; org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController; publishing core=Y_shard1_replica1 state=down collection=Y
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.125; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [Z_shard1_replica1]  CLOSING SolrCore org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@3e6f43bd
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.125; org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; closing DirectUpdateHandler2{commits=0,autocommits=0,soft autocommits=0,optimizes=0,rollbacks=0,expungeDeletes=0,docsPending=0,
adds=0,deletesById=0,deletesByQuery=0,errors=0,cumulative_adds=0,cumulative_deletesById=0,cumulative_deletesByQuery=0,cumulative_errors=0,transaction_logs_total_size=0,transaction_logs_total_number=0}
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.126; org.apache.solr.update.SolrCoreState; Closing SolrCoreState
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.126; org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState; SolrCoreState ref count has reached 0 - closing IndexWriter
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.126; org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState; closing IndexWriter with IndexWriterCloser
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.129; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [Z_shard1_replica1] Closing main searcher on request.
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.130; org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory; Closing StandardDirectoryFactory - 2 directories currently being tracked
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.132; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader$2; A cluster state change: WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:NodeDataChanged path:/clusterstate.json, has occurred - updating
... (live nodes size: 2)
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.133; org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory; looking to close /data/solr/Z_shard1_replica1/data/index [CachedDir<<refCount=0;path=/data/solr/Z_shard1_replica1/data/index;done=false>>]
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.133; org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory; Closing directory: /data/solr/Z_shard1_replica1/data/index
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.134; org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory; looking to close /data/solr/Z_shard1_replica1/data [CachedDir<<refCount=0;path=/data/solr/Z_shard1_replica1/data;done=false>>]
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.134; org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory; Closing directory: /data/solr/Z_shard1_replica1/data
INFO  - 2015-11-24 00:00:02.134; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [X_Openbaar_shard1_replica2]  CLOSING SolrCore org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@78
```

Does somebody have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Sounds like a Cron job or perhaps an invalid service definition. Nothing else can explain this happening multiple times precisely at midnight. I would check those two.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, offcourse I have checked crontabs for each user including root on the system. What do you mean with service definition?

Comment: How do you start the Solr? Is it a service? If so, you must have a definition somewhere (init.d?). Check that. The other things to try is to change the STOP port number or to run network and/or process trace over the 5 minutes spinning the shutdown. Basically, this should not be happening normally, so it has to be something *interesting* on your system.